# How do I put a register into an array index in MASM?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm

I'm having a really hard time with arrays in MASM. I don't understand how to put the value of a register into an index of an array. I can't seem to find where arr[i] is. What is it I'm missing or what do I have wrong? 
Thanks for your time!

C++ code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    extern"C"
    {
        char intToBinary(char *, int, int);
    }

    int main()
    {
        const int SIZE = 16;
        char arr[SIZE] = { '/0' };
        cout << "What integer do you want converted?" << endl;
        cin >> decimal;

        char value = intToBinary(arr, SIZE, decimal);

        return 0;
    }
```

Assembly code:

```
.686
.model flat

.code

_intToBinary PROC ; named _test because C automatically prepends an underscode, it is needed to interoperate
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp ; stack pointer to ebp

    mov ebx,[ebp+8] ; address of first array element
    mov ecx,[ebp+12] ; number of elements in array
    mov edx, 0      ;has to be 0 to check remainder
    mov esi, 2      ;the new divisor
    mov edi, 12

    LoopMe:
        add ebx, 4
        xor edx, edx            ;keep this 0 at all divisions
        div esi                 ;divide eax by 2
        inc ebx                 ;increment by 1
        mov [ebp + edi], edx    ;put edx into the next array index

        add edi, 4              ;add 4 bytes to find next index
        cmp ecx, ebx            ;compare iterator to number of elements (16)
    jg LoopMe

    pop ebp                 ;return 
    ret
_intToBinary ENDP

END
```

Comment: Is this on Windows? I assume it is, but could you confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In your C++ code

- `decimal` is not defined.
- `'/0'` is invalid character literal. Use `\`, not `/`, to write escape sequences in C++.
- `value` isn't used.

Your code should be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern"C"
{
    char intToBinary(char *, int, int);
}

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 16;
    char arr[SIZE] = { '\0' };
    int decimal;
    cout << "What integer do you want converted?" << endl;
    cin >> decimal;

    intToBinary(arr, SIZE, decimal);
    for (int i = SIZE - 1; i >= 0; i--) cout << arr[i];
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

#### In your assembly code

- You stored the "address of first array element" to `ebx` by `mov ebx,[ebp+8]`, so the address of `arr` will be there.
  Unfortunately, it is destroyed by `add ebx, 4` and `inc ebx`.
- "put edx into the next array index" No, `[ebp + edi]` isn't the next array index and it is destoying data on the stack. It is very bad.
- Don't add 4 bytes to "find next index" if your size of `char` is 1 byte.

Your code should be like this (Sorry, this is nasm code because I am unfamiliar to masm):

```
bits 32

global _intToBinary
_intToBinary:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp ; stack pointer to ebp
    push esi ; save this register before breaking in the code
    push edi ; save this, too
    push ebx ; save this, too
    mov ebx, [ebp + 8] ; address of first array element
    mov ecx, [ebp + 12] ; number of elements in array
    mov eax, [ebp + 16] ; the number to convert
    xor edi, edi ; the index of array to store
    mov esi, 2 ; the new divisor

    LoopMe:
        xor edx, edx ; keep this 0 at all divisions
        div esi ; divide eax by 2
        add dl, 48 ; convert the number in dl to a character representing it
        mov [ebx + edi], dl ; put dl into the next array index
        inc edi ; add 1 byte to find next index
        cmp ecx, edi ; compare iterator to number of elements
    jg LoopMe

    xor eax, eax ; return 0
    pop ebx ; restore the saved register
    pop edi ; restore this, too
    pop esi ; restore this, too
    mov esp, ebp ; restore stack pointer
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Note that this code will store the binary text in reversed order, so I wrote the C++ code to print them from back to front.
Also note that there are no terminating null character in `arr`, so do not do `cout << arr;`.

Comment: You can push what seems to be addresses from registers into the stack to be reached at a later time just by calling pop and the register you want?

How does [ebp + 16] equal the decimal entered? Isn't that the first element in the array?

How, exactly, do you find the array? Just "[ebx]"?

Comment: Yes, you can push & pop memory addresses because they are just 32-bit values on IA-32. After executing the function prologue, there will be old value of `ebp` on `[ebp+0]`, return address on `[ebp+4]`, 1st arg on `[ebp+8]`, 2nd arg on `[ebp+12]`, and 3rd arg on `[ebp+16]` if each arguments are 4 bytes. For that reason, the (address of the first element of) array will be `[ebp+8]` as it is passed as 1st argument, and the `decimal` will be `[ebp+16]` as it is passed as 3rd argument. Finally, **as you wrote**, the address of first array element will be `[ebp+8]`, so visit there to find the array.

Answer (score 1):

You have the address of the first array element in `ebx`, and `edi` is your loop counter.  So `mov [ebx + edi], edx` would store `edx` into `arr[edi]`.

Also note that your loop condition is wrong (your `cmp` is comparing the number of elements against the starting address of the array.)

Avoid `div` whenever possible.  To divide by two, right-shift by one.  `div` is very slow (like 10 to 30 times slower than a shift).

---

BTW, since you have a choice of which registers to use (out of the ones the ABI says you're allowed to clobber without saving/restoring), `edi` is used for a "destination" pointer by convention (i.e. when it doesn't cost any extra instructions), while `esi` is used as a "source" pointer.

Speaking of the ABI, you need to save/restore `ebx` in functions that use it, same as `ebp`.  It keeps its value across function calls (because any ABI-compliant function you call preserves it).  I forget which other registers are callee-saved in the 32bit ABI.  You can check at the helpful links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  32bit is obsolete; 64bit has a more efficient ABI, and includes SSE2 as part of the baseline.

Comment: 32-bit `edx` won't fit in 8-bit `arr[edi]`.

Comment: "To divide by two, right-shift by one." yes, and you can use `and eax, 1` to calculate the remainder of `eax / 2`.

Comment: @MikeCAT: yeah, I was just noticing that bug in his code, that he defined the array as `char`.  I was fooled by the asm that incremented the pointer by 4, and was going to add to my answer that using an `int8_t` array would be more efficient!  Then realized that he maybe wanted a string, not an array of integer zero and one...

Comment: Actually, you'd probably want `setc dl` or something, to set a byte to zero or one according to the the carry flag.  If you mask the register you're shifting, you destroy the value that's still there (so you'd need a `mov / and` combination).  `shift` sets CF to the last bit shifted out, so you're all set to use a `setc dl` or `sbb edx, edx` (to set edx to 0 or -1).